# Create a view processing the original table using sqlite db

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I am working on a C# Winforms application and trying to create a view in sqlite using the following table structure:

[image]

and this is how the view should look like:
[image]

This is the sql command but does not produce the view as wished:

```
SELECT tbl1.Time AS C1,
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE Time = T.Time AND T.VarId = 2) AS C2, 
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE Time = T.Time AND T.VarId = 3) AS C3,
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE Time = T.Time AND T.VarId = 4) AS C4, 
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE Time = T.Time AND T.VarId = 5) AS C5,
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE Time = T.Time AND T.VarId = 6) AS C6, 
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE Time = T.Time AND T.VarId = 7) AS C7
FROM tbl1
WHERE tbl1.VarId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
GROUP BY tbl1.Time
ORDER BY tbl1.Time
```

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a subquery, a column name without a table name (like `Time`) refers to the *innermost* table, in this case, `T`.
This means that `Time = T.Time` is interpreted as `T.Time = T.Time`.

For a correlated subquery, you must compare a column of the inner table (`T.Time`) and a column of the outer table (`tbl1.Time`):

```sql
SELECT tbl1.Time AS Time,
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE T.Time = tbl1.Time AND T.VarId = 1) AS C1,
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE T.Time = tbl1.Time AND T.VarId = 2) AS C2,
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE T.Time = tbl1.Time AND T.VarId = 3) AS C3,
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE T.Time = tbl1.Time AND T.VarId = 4) AS C4,
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE T.Time = tbl1.Time AND T.VarId = 5) AS C5,
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE T.Time = tbl1.Time AND T.VarId = 6) AS C6,
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE T.Time = tbl1.Time AND T.VarId = 7) AS C7,
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE T.Time = tbl1.Time AND T.VarId = 8) AS C8,
(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM tbl1 AS T WHERE T.Time = tbl1.Time AND T.VarId = 9) AS C9,
tbl1.Method AS Method    -- ???
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY tbl1.Time
ORDER BY tbl1.Time
```

Comment: However, when I use it in my original table and not in above demo table the query takes a while to execute.

Comment: Optimizing the query is a different question. (But you probably need only an index on the `Time` column.)

Comment: Hi CL I have to modify the view, the new requirement is to get the varId and C1, C2... from another table.  Any hint?

Comment: Hint: please read the tooltip of the "add a comment" link. Then click "Ask Question".